# monacaでのWebDAV URL

Tags: monaca

以前はmonacaの左下にWebDAVがあったと思うのですが現在はどこで見れますか？

初歩的な質問ですみませんが、探しても見つかりません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

2015/09/11にMonaca公式から下記の通り告知がありました。
現在は利用できなくなっているようです。

> 誠に勝手ながらWebDAV機能を段階的に廃止いたします。ローカル環境との同期にはMonaca
>   CLIもしくはLocalkitをご利用ください。

https://ja.monaca.io/headline/